# Accessing dataframe with multiindex with date intermittently failing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a multiindex from which I am attempting access a row from. The dataframe can be recreated with the following:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
import pytz
from pandas import Timestamp

utc = pytz.UTC

data = {
    "date": [
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).replace(minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date(),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date(),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=1),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=1),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=2),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=2),
    ],
    "status": ["in_progress", "in_progress", "done", "in_progress", "done", "in_progress", "done"],
    "issue_count": [20, 18, 2, 14, 6, 10, 10],
    "points": [100, 90, 10, 70, 30, 50, 50],
    "stories": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "tasks": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
    "bugs": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "subtasks": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "assignee": ["Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

breakdown = df.groupby(["date", "status"]).sum()
d = date(2020, 6, 3)
done = breakdown.loc[d, "done"]
```

The line:

```
done = breakdown.loc[d, "done"]
```

fails intermitently on about 1/10th of runs with the following stack trace:

```
...
  File "/Users/<name>/miniconda3/envs/<repo>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 2979, in _get_level_indexer
    i = level_codes.searchsorted(code, side="left")
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'slice'
```

I tried debugging the code and saw that on the failing line, `level_codes.searchsorted(code, side="left")`, was a slice instead of an `int` so the search was failing but I do not know why this is occuring and why only intermittently.

Comment: It's a bug in `pandas` - see the issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39585).