# read_pickle failing stochastically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I saved to a pickle file. When I load it with `read_pickle` it fails with the following error on roughly 1/10th of runs:

```
ValueError: Level values must be unique: [Timestamp('2020-06-03 15:59:59.999999+0000', tz='UTC'), datetime.date(2020, 6, 3), datetime.date(2020, 6, 4), datetime.date(2020, 6, 5)] on level 0
```

What is causing this stochastic behaviour?

The issue can be reproduced with the following:

```py
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
import pytz
from pandas import Timestamp

utc = pytz.UTC

data = {
    "date": [
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).replace(minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date(),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date(),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=1),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=1),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=2),
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00").replace(tzinfo=utc).date() + timedelta(days=2),
    ],
    "status": ["in_progress", "in_progress", "done", "in_progress", "done", "in_progress", "done"],
    "issue_count": [20, 18, 2, 14, 6, 10, 10],
    "points": [100, 90, 10, 70, 30, 50, 50],
    "stories": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "tasks": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
    "bugs": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "subtasks": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "assignee": ["Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(["date", "status"]).sum()

df.to_pickle("~/failing_df.pkl")
pd.read_pickle("~/failing_df.pkl")
```

Comment: why don't you use csv? Why pkl?

Comment: Familiarity I suppose - give me a minute and I'll try to recreate with csv.

Comment: use `pandas.to_csv(filename)` and `pandas.read_csv(file_name`

Comment: So I pushed the csv but it does not recreate the issue. However, it does not load as the same multiindex - so I'm guessing that's related?

Comment: It is flattening the `multiindex`, you can use `pandas.groupby`

Comment: I've done that but still not having any joy recreating the issue. I'm probably creating the original dataframe in an unrecommended manner which is leading to issues down the line.

Comment: oh, no problem, you can post your issue to stack overflow anytime :)

Comment: I was unable to reproduce with `to_csv` but I have attached code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: your code worked fine on my computer :/

Comment: Well that opens up a whole new can of worms. Just to check - did you run it multiple times? I just ran it 60 times and it threw the error 12 times.

Comment: Also, it's not just my local machine - it's also failing in a similar manner on production. I'm also seeing this (presumably related?) issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65927344/accessing-dataframe-with-multiindex-with-date-intermittently-failing

Comment: It's a bug in `pandas` - see the issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39585).

Answer (score 0):

try `to_csv()` or `to_dict()`

```py
# write it to csv
df.to_csv('temp.csv')
# read it from csv
df2 = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
df2.set_index(['date', 'status'], inplace=True)
```

or optionally

```py
df_dict = df.to_dict()

# pickle it
df.to_pickle('temp.pkl')

# unpickle it   
df2 = pd.read_pickle('temp.pkl')
```

Comment: It's not necessarily that I can't get around the issue but more why am I seeing the behaviour that I am (i.e. the intermitent failing).

Comment: oh, then maybe something other causing the problem